# Internet speed too slow

Tags: 16.04, wireless, internet

I have problem with internet on Ubuntu 16.04. My computer is connected via Wi-Fi. On Windows10 my Test Speed result is 39 Mbps and on Ubuntu is 11 Mbps. I don't know how to solve this.
Any ideas?

EDIT: Upload speed is same as on Windows but download speed is different.

Comment: which wifi card do you have? which drivers are you using? is there coexistant bluetooth?

Comment: @ravery
RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter. 
Yes, there is a bluetooth.
There is a very long list of drivers when I check.

Comment: I'm an expert with your particular card but there has been some issue with bluetooth interferance. @pilot6 knows the fix for the interference. There are updated drivers from lwfinger's github, but third party drivers have to be signed if you are using kernel 4.4 later with secure boot on

Comment: @ravery Hm, we are waiting for pilot6 now for solution or what?

Comment: yes, he should get a notice since I tagged him in the comment. I can't remember the command he gave on another question

Comment: Ok ,we are waiting for pilot6, thank you @ravery.

Comment: Is this a HP computer?

Comment: @Jeremy31 Yes HP computer.

Comment: What model, some are using only one antenna wire and that causes some problems?

Comment: @Jeremy31 model HP 15-ay103nm...

Comment: @Jeremy31 help?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 and upload the results to paste.ubuntu.com and post the URL